# An integral with the Gamma function

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Let $c$ be a positive constant. Can you evaluate the following integral?

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{cx+1}}{\Gamma(1+cx)}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Ps. Do you have some advices or tricks to solve this type of integrals, or variants of the above one?

Comment: Does it make any sense or is it just for fun / interest ?

Comment: I have to solve this integral as a piece of the expression of the variance function of a measure-valued stochastic process.

Comment: Since it's defined integral, you could always just approximate...

Comment: I think he was meaning whether it is possible to obtain a closed formula as a function of c; anyway, I didnt really understand the comment of Maleki above

Comment: For what $c$ the integral can exist at all ? I am not sure that the condition $e^{c-1}\le c^c$ and therefore $c>0$ is enough.

Comment: @JackLondon: a variance and there is no square? That looks weird. What is the origin of the super-fast-growing factor $x^{cx+1}$?

Comment: Use the definition of the Gamma function?